# How to disable buttons on ng-blur when data doesn't match from database while changing the value of drodown

Tags: php, html, angularjs, laravel

I have two columns and 3 buttons in a form and i am using data-ng-blur to disable these buttons until user id and password don't match in database. and it's working fine for the first time but when i change the user id with the same password without  refreshing the page, my form buttons are still enabled while the password is incorrect. solutions please.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class='control-label'>Executive Name*</label>
        <select class='form-control' data-ng-model="visit.executive_id" type="text" >
            <option value="" disabled>---Select Executive---</option>
            <option data-ng-repeat="exe in executive track by $index" value="<%exe.value%>"><%exe.text%></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class='control-label'>Password* (Use your Mob. No)</label>
        <input type="password" class='form-control' name="password" data-ng-blur="login()" data-ng-model="visit.password" type="text">
    </div>
</div>          
<div class='col-md-offset-4 col-md-4'>
    <button class='btn-lg btn-block btn-primary' data-ng-click="visitsite()" ng-disabled="valid">
        <center>Site Visit Receipt</center>
    </button>
    <button class='btn-lg btn-block btn-primary' data-ng-click="printblank()" ng-disabled="valid">
        <center>Blank Site Visit</center>
    </button>
    <button class='btn-lg btn-block btn-primary' data-ng-click="propvisit()" ng-disabled="valid">
        <center>Blank Property Visit</center>
    </button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.extend($scope, {

            valid: true,
            login: function () {

                var credentials = $scope.visit;

                $serviceModel.login(credentials).then(function (result) {

                    if (result.data.success) {

                        $scope.valid = false;
                    }

                    else {

                        $scope.valid = true;
                        alert('Incorrect Password');
                    }

                });

            }
  }])
```

Comment: How you validate if the user name and password is match without database call?

Comment: for the first time it's validate but without refreshing the page how can i send another request to database?

Comment: Add a submit button. On blur input is a bad way to do this from a usability standpoint.

Comment: so why in case of password it works? when i fill both the field correctly my all buttons get enabled but without refreshing the page when i change password only with the same user id my form buttons goes disable but vice versa it doesn't work. why?

Comment: You can have a way out, use ng-init on the div having class row as follow, <div class="row" ng-init="valid=true">

Comment: NO! it's not working

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem lies in a fact that *login()* function is not invoked when you change user id. Password field has *data-ng-blur* directive to trigger *login()* function once focus is lost on password field for your functionality to work while a similar directive for select element (which is responsible for user id selection) is missing for desired functionality to work.

Instead of

```
<select class='form-control' data-ng-model="visit.executive_id" type="text" > ...
```

try using

```
<select class='form-control' data-ng-model="visit.executive_id" data-ng-blur="login()" type="text" > ...
```

While we are at it by using directives for select element, instead of using *data-ng-model* directive, you can use *ng-change* directive that is specialised for select element use, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#usage

```
<select class='form-control' data-ng-model="visit.executive_id" ng-change="login()" type="text" > ...
```

Good luck.